# Find the hidden logic (Easy)

Tags: number-sequence

I created this puzzle. What is so special about this number sequence? What is the logic behind this sequence?
$$63072, 123172, 123173, 123174, 123175, 123176, 123177, 123178, 123179, 63081, 63082, 63083, 63085, 123187, 123189, 123190, 63092, 63093, 63094, 123195, 63097, 123198, 123105, 123108, 63012, 63015, 123116$$

Hint 1:

> What do you spend the most?

Hint 2:

> How much do you spend it?

Hint 3:

> How accurate is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think these are the

> dates when a [leap second](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/leapseconds.html) was added

However, they do not seem to match

> the dates at [IETF](https://www.ietf.org/timezones/data/leap-seconds.list)

The hints are

> the thing you spend the most is time

Answer (score 2):

I think they are

> dates... Not so sure. The numbers starting with 1231 are new year eves.

Comment: I sincerely apologize for not appreciating your effort so far, @Displaymaths. You were right though. Nice work and good guess.